# Вопрос по поводу json

Tags: python, json, list, set

есть JSON файл. Хочу сделать из него новый словарь, в котором будет только название, цену. Для этого нужно удалить некоторые пары ключ-значение.
Пример словаря:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 2164181,
            "key": "ne63060019k9190a",
            "name": "GeForce RTX 3060 Dual 12GB GDDR6 NE63060019K9-190AD",
            "full_name": "Palit GeForce RTX 3060 Dual 12GB GDDR6 NE63060019K9-190AD",
            "name_prefix": "\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430",
            "extended_name": "\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430 Palit GeForce RTX 3060 Dual 12GB GDDR6 NE63060019K9-190AD",
            "status": "active",
            "images": {
                "header": "//content2.onliner.by/catalog/device/header/5b4d031565755192170ac9ba5b6c56bb.jpeg",
                "icon": null
            },
            "image_size": [],
            "description": "12 \u0413\u0411 GDDR6 LHR, 1320 \u041c\u0413\u0446 / 1777 \u041c\u0413\u0446, 3584sp, 28 RT-\u044f\u0434\u0435\u0440, \u0442\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u043b\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439, 192 \u0431\u0438\u0442, 2 \u0441\u043b\u043e\u0442\u0430, \u043f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 8 pin, HDMI, DisplayPort",
            "micro_description": "1320 \u041c\u0413\u0446/1777 \u041c\u0413\u0446",
            "html_url": "https://catalog.onliner.by/videocard/palit/ne63060019k9190a",
            "reviews": {
                "rating": 46,
                "count": 34,
                "html_url": "https://catalog.onliner.by/videocard/palit/ne63060019k9190a/reviews",
                "url": "https://catalog.api.onliner.by/products/ne63060019k9190a/reviews"
            },
            "review_url": null,
            "color_code": null,
            "prices": {
                "price_min": {
                    "amount": "1248.67",
                    "currency": "BYN",
                    "converted": {
                        "BYN": {
                            "amount": "1248.67",
                            "currency": "BYN"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "price_max": {
                    "amount": "1728.45",
                    "currency": "BYN",
                    "converted": {
                        "BYN": {
                            "amount": "1728.45",
                            "currency": "BYN"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "offers": {
                    "count": 45
                },
                "html_url": "https://catalog.onliner.by/videocard/palit/ne63060019k9190a/prices",
                "url": "https://shop.api.onliner.by/products/ne63060019k9190a/positions"
            },
            "max_installment_terms": {
                "all": {
                    "term": 4,
                    "label": "\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0440\u043e\u0447\u043a\u0430 \u0434\u043e 4 \u043c\u0435\u0441\u044f\u0446\u0435\u0432"
                }
            },
            "max_cobrand_cashback": {
                "percentage": 5,
                "label": "5% \u043d\u0430 \u00ab\u041a\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u00bb"
            },
            "sale": {
                "is_on_sale": false,
                "discount": 0,
                "min_prices_median": {
                    "amount": "1284.57",
                    "currency": "BYN"
                }
            },
            "second": {
                "offers_count": 1,
                "min_price": {
                    "amount": "999.00",
                    "currency": "BYN"
                },
                "max_price": {
                    "amount": "999.00",
                    "currency": "BYN"
                }
            },
            "forum": {
                "topic_id": 24538032,
                "topic_url": "https://forum.onliner.by/viewtopic.php?t=24538032",
                "post_url": "https://forum.onliner.by/posting.php?mode=newtopic&amp;f=163&amp;device=ne63060019k9190a",
                "replies_count": 226
            },
            "url": "https://catalog.api.onliner.by/products/ne63060019k9190a",
            "advertise": null,
            "stickers": [
                {
                    "type": "customers_choice",
                    "label": "\u0412\u044b\u0431\u043e\u0440 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0439",
                    "text": "\u0422\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440 \u0432\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432 \u0442\u043e\u043f-5 \u043f\u043e \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043c \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0439 \u0432 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0435",
                    "color": "4c7b0e",
                    "bg_color": "ecf6df",
                    "html_url": null
                },
                {
                    "type": "recommended",
                    "label": "Onl\u00edner \u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u0442",
                    "text": "",
                    "color": "0b6fd3",
                    "bg_color": "dfebff",
                    "html_url": null
                }
            ],
            "prime_info": {
                "available": false
            },
            "by_parts_info": {
                "monthly_payment": {
                    "amount": "49.59",
                    "currency": "BYN"
                }
            }
        },
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, но не получается:

```
data_dict = json.loads(names)
print(data_dict["products"][0]["key"])
for i in data_dict:
    del data_dict["products"][i]["id"]
    del data_dict["products"][i]["key"]
```

Поясните пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

# Читаю ваш json из файла
with open('text.json') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    templates = json.loads(file_content)
data_dict = templates['products']

# Создаю новый список
data_products = {"products": []}

for i in data_dict:
    product = {}
    product['name'] = i['name']
    product['prices'] = i['prices']['price_min']['amount']

    data_products["products"].append(product)  # Добовляю Данные о товаре в общий список
print(data_products)
```

Этот код читает ваш json и вместо того, чтобы удалять лишние столбцы, он выберет то, что вам нужно и сохранит в новом словаре.(В данном случае только название, цену)
Вывод:

```
{'products': [{'name': 'GeForce RTX 3060 Dual 12GB GDDR6 NE63060019K9-190AD', 'prices': '1248.67'}]}
```